# How to display an alert message by using JQuery instead than Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, alert

I created a html webpage which contains a form. I linked it to a javascript file, which tells the browser to display an alert message whenever the user lets empty the fields.
The html structure is the following:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title> title </title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="example.css">

</head>
<body>

    <h1>Modulo di richiesta informazioni</h1>

    <h2>Inserisci i tuoi dati:</h2>

    <form onsubmit="return validateForm()">

        <select name="status">
            <option value="Sig.">Sig.</option>
            <option value="Sig.ra">Sig.ra</option>
            <option value="Sig.na">Sig.na</option>
        </select>
        <br>

        <label>Nome:</label><br>
        <input type="text" name="name" id="name" value="scrivi il nome"><br>

        <label>Cognome:</label><br>
        <input type="text" name="surname" id="surname"><br>

        <label>email:</label><br>
        <input type="email" name="email" id="email">
        <br>


        <label>Numero di tel:</label><br>
         <input type="number" name="numero" id="numero">
         <br>

        <label>
        Inserisci la tua richiesta:</label>
        <br>
        <textarea name="commenti">Scrivi qui la tua richiesta:</textarea>
         <br>


        <label> Seleziona il servizio per il quale desideri richiedere informazioni:</label><br>

        <label> Chatbot</label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="Service" value="Chatbot">
        <label>Assistente virtuale</label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="Service" value="Assistente">
        <label> MySpoofer.it </label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="Service" value="MySpoofer">

        <br>


        <input type="submit" name="submit"> 
    </form>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="2_jsfile.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

The Javascript snippet linked to it is the following:

```
function validateForm(){
    var x = document.getElementById('surname').value;
    if(x == ""){
        alert("Inserisci il cognome");
        return false;   
    } 
    var y = document.getElementById('email').value;
    if (y == "") {
        alert("Scrivi il tuo indirizzo e-mail");
        return false;
    }
    var z = document.getElementById('numero').value;
    if (z == "") {
        alert("Inserisci il tuo numero di telefono");
        return false;
    }
```

In the *else if statements*, I want to substitute the alert method with the following JQuery method to obtain a message which displays a message to the user, but it doesn't work, therefore I am not sure it's a valid method:

```
    function validateForm(){
    var x = document.getElementById('surname').value;
    if(x == ""){
        $("<form>").html("Si prega di compilare i campi 
       con i dati richiesti");  
        return false;   
    } 
    var y = document.getElementById('email').value;
    if (y == "") {
        $("form").html("<div>Si prega di compilare i campi con i dati richiesti</div>");
        return false;
    }
    var z = document.getElementById('numero').value;
    if (z == "") {
        $("form").html("<div>Si prega di compilare i campi con i dati richiesti</div>");
        return false;
    }

}
```

Whow can I display an alert message by using JQuery instead than classic Javascript?

Comment: I am assuming that above jQuery should not work as $("<form>") is not a valid selector, correct that and it should replace the form content with your HTML structure.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `jQuery UI` Dialog for your requirement `$( "#dialog" ).dialog();`

```js
 $( function() {
    $( "#dialog" ).dialog();
  } );
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>jQuery UI Dialog - Default functionality</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
 
<div id="dialog" title="Error Title">
  <p>The content error here.</p>
</div>
 
 
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do the validation also without jQuery UI. Change your validate function to something like

```js
function validateForm(){ 
 $('form div.msg').remove();
 var ret=0;
 $('#name,#surname,#numero').each(
  function(i,o){
    if (o.value==''){
     $(o).after('<div class="msg">'+o.id+': Si prega di compilare i campi con i dati richiesti</div>');
     ret++;
    }
  });
 return !ret
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>Modulo di richiesta informazioni</h1>

    <h2>Inserisci i tuoi dati:</h2>

    <form onsubmit="return validateForm()">

        <select name="status">
            <option value="Sig.">Sig.</option>
            <option value="Sig.ra">Sig.ra</option>
            <option value="Sig.na">Sig.na</option>
        </select>
        <br>

        <label>Nome:</label><br>
        <input type="text" name="name" id="name" value="scrivi il nome"><br>

        <label>Cognome:</label><br>
        <input type="text" name="surname" id="surname"><br>

        <label>email:</label><br>
        <input type="email" name="email" id="email">
        <br>


        <label>Numero di tel:</label><br>
         <input type="number" name="numero" id="numero">
         <br>

        <label>
        Inserisci la tua richiesta:</label>
        <br>
        <textarea name="commenti">Scrivi qui la tua richiesta:</textarea>
         <br>


        <label> Seleziona il servizio per il quale desideri richiedere informazioni:</label><br>

        <label> Chatbot</label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="Service" value="Chatbot">
        <label>Assistente virtuale</label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="Service" value="Assistente">
        <label> MySpoofer.it </label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="Service" value="MySpoofer">

        <br>


        <input type="submit" name="submit"> 
    </form>
```

This will append a `<div>` with an error message under each of the targeted input fields, if it was found to be empty. Before this happens all potentially existing messages of previous errors will be removed by `$('form div.msg').remove()`.

**Edit:**

If you *really* wanted to, you could shorten the above function even further, using `.filter()`instead of `.each()`, but the result is probably less readable:

```
function validateForm(){ 
 $('form div.msg').remove();
 return !$('#name,#surname,#numero')  // the ! negates the calculated length ...
   .filter((i,o)=>o.value==''                // is field empty?
      ? $(o).after('<div class="msg">'+o.id  // yes: place message!
                   +': Si prega di compilare i campi con i dati richiesti</div>')
      : false                                // no:  remove from jquery object
    ).length;  // length: number of empty fields
}
```